# RShiny showing plots conditionally

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I built a RShiny Dashboard to display participants' own data of an ESM study, after logging in with their study ID. Participants got to choose which themes they wanted to monitor in the ESM study, hence not all participants have data for all variables.

In their personal dashboard I want to show only the plots of the variables they have data for. If there is no data, the column is *NA*, and I want to show an image instead of the plot.

I will not share the whole code here, but only the relevant parts. Here is the code I tried:

**In the ui part**

```
fluidRow(  
     box(
       title = "Zingeving en voldoening", status = "success", solidHeader = TRUE, width = 4, collapsible = TRUE,
       if(diarydata_compliance[which(diarydata_compliance$ID == IDnum()),zingeving_selected] == 1) {
         plotOutput("plot_zingeving")
         
       } else {
         imageOutput("logo_POP")
       }
       ))
```

**Then, defining the outputs in the server part:**

```
##ImageBox "LOGO_POP"
  output$logo_POP = renderImage({
    return(list(src = "~/Diary Enik Test/fig_output/logo_POP_transparant.png", 
                deleteFile = FALSE,
                width = "200",
                height = "200"))
    
  }) #End renderImage

 ##Output: Plot Zingeving en Voldoening
  #diarydata_themes[which(diarydata_themes$ID == IDnum()),] makes sure that only data is included from the participant with the entered ID.
   output$plot_zingeving = renderPlot({
      ggplot(diarydata_themes[which(diarydata_themes$ID == IDnum()),], mapping = aes(x = zingeving_voldoening)) + 
      geom_bar(aes(fill = Enik_dich),
               position = "dodge") +
      labs(x = "Heb je dingen gedaan die belangrijk zijn?",
           y = "") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("Bij Enik geweest" = "#6eb76e",
                                    "Niet bij Enik geweest" = "#e98357")) +
      theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
            legend.title = element_blank(),
            axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
            axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
            legend.position = "top")
    
      })#end renderPlot
```

When I run it and try to launch the app I get an error:
Error:
! Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
• You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.

At first I build the Shiny App without the if condition in the ui part: then the plots showed correctly. Only, when there was no data for a plot variable, it still showed a plot with NAs [see here, this ppn has no data on "Zingeving en voldoening"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jybfp.png). I want that replaced by an image.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are trying to reference `IDnum()` within the `box()` call UI. Instead, use `uiOutput`, and in the server, change what that UI element is based on IDNum()

1. So here is the change to ui

```
fluidRow(  
  box(
    title = "Zingeving en voldoening", status = "success", solidHeader = TRUE, width = 4, collapsible = TRUE,
    uiOutput("cond_output")
  )
)
```

2. Here is the type of change you'll need to ADD in server

```
output$cond_output <- renderUI({
  if(diarydata_compliance[which(diarydata_compliance$ID == IDnum()),zingeving_selected] == 1) {
    plotOutput("plot_zingeving")
  } else {
    imageOutput("logo_POP")
  }
})
```

Thus, your conditional statement is now evaluated in the `renderUI()`; if your conditional statement is met, the the `cond_output` element becomes a `plotOutput`, but if it is not met, then it becomes an `imageOutput`.

Comment: This partly solved the problem yet created a bunch of other ones... 
- the first row with valueboxes does not pick up the right data (sometimes it works, sometimes not, can't figure out what happens, nothing has changed there, right??)
- the plots are not always hidden and when displayed the data is not always correct (not from that ID)... This worked out before I installed the conditions...

Comment: When i only load row 1 in the app (so not the rows with the plots), the data for the renderValue boxes are correct... So something goes wrong when adding the plot code...

Comment: You are talking about things that don’t appear in your original question.  Perhaps open a new one if you have a new question?

Comment: These things came up after making the change as proposed in the solution. I am not sure what to post when I post a new question: should I just share all the code? That is a lot... I am new to Stackoverflow so not sure how to handle these things. Thanks again!

Comment: I made a follow up post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73935380/rshiny-showing-plots-conditionally-follow-up